# Downside of 'Turbo' mode on rice cooker?

Tags: rice-cooker

My rice cooker has an optional Turbo mode when cooking rice.  The mode is off by default.

As I understand, the upside is that rice cooks faster.  What's the downside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have one of the Cuckoo cookers with a Turbo mode. The one (slight) downside is that white rice will come out a bit more... gooey? with the Turbo cooking. It's not bad and seems to primarily affect smaller batches. If you let the rice rest a bit and plan on tossing it with oil or butter (or just don't mind stickier rice), it's definitely workable.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have a model which seals tightly and thus is a type of pressure cooker.  Turbo mode no doubt essentially pressure cooks the rice so that it can reach temperatures above 212 F / 100 C and thus cook faster.  (The Cuckoo product line seems to have this as a distinguishing feature.)

There really is no downside to pressure cooking grains or legumes from a culinary perspective, and the modern equipment is quite safe.

Comment: This answer seems to be based on conjecture, not first-hand knowledge. -1